# c++ returns 7.45058 instead of 0

Tags: c++

I'v ran into another anomaly:

```
float T = 19.0 / 99.0;
float moo = (99.0 * T) - 19.0;
```

as expected, T = 0.191919, however 'moo' is meant to be 0 but instead is 7.450586.
I can only presume some form of casting is once again required somewhere.

Comment: Try to use `double` instead of `float`! Also a good read: [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf)

Comment: I get 7.45058e-08, a very small number. You probably did, too.

Comment: Are you sure it's `7.450586`, and not `7.450586e-008` or some other really small exponent?

Comment: I also get 7.45058e-08: https://ideone.com/lMJqDK but 0 if you use double instead of float: https://ideone.com/spuUn8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this and you will get 0 on moo

float T = 19.0**f** / 99.0**f**;
float moo = (99.0**f** * T) - 19.0**f**;

Also the value on moo without this is not 7.45, it is 7.45058e-08 which is almost zero.

Comment: I guess that is some kind of compiler optimization. On ideone I still get 7.45058e-08

Comment: I am using Apple LLVM 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Since any floating point numbers are represented in 2's complement notation in c++.you will usually get approximate values , while manipulating floating point values .So 7.450586e-008 is exact behaviour . If you need more precision use double.